# How to fix ssl connection issue :" ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3337)

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I know there have been similar questions around and i have looked through them and ended up asking again.

To explain the problem at hand:
I have to establish a secured connection to a server
for which i have been given with a PRIVATE key, Certificate and a CA certificate.

I put all of these in one file called "one.pem"
and here is the code i wrote to establish a connection.

```
    import socket
import ssl
import os

HOST, PORT, CERT, KEY= 'XX.XX.XX.XX', 1234, "one.pem", "private.pem"



exists = os.path.exists(CERT)
print(exists)
exists = os.path.exists(KEY)
print(exists)

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)

context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT, keyfile=None, password=None)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST,certfile=CERT) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
        try:
            ssock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        except ssl.SSLError as err:
            print("Error Connecting : {}".format(str(err)))
```

i took examples from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) 
Any hints, ideas are welcome.

Edit:
This is how my "one.pem" looks like ( it is in the same folder as the python file)

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
... (private key in base64 encoding) ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (certficte in base64 encoding) ...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (CA certficte in base64 encoding) ...
-----END CERTIFICATE----
```

Edit:
error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssl_connect.py", line 16, in <module>
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile=CERT)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3337)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full and exact error message you've got including the stack trace (i.e. where the error happened in your program)

Comment: i added the error message, more so , i am running it from git bash on a windows machine. $ python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: This error can happen if the private key does not match the certificate. How did you verify that key matches the certificate?

Comment: These are provided by server side to connect, i have a RSA private key, certificate and a CA certificate.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly you did not verify yourself that the key matches the certificate. See for example [here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/684/17/how-do-i-verify-that-a-private-key-matches-a-certificate-openssl) for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: i did check as per above steps:  $  openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in private.pem | openssl md5
(stdin)= d2c6074652768d7a5f5b09b412cf2adb

tatirs1@INENTATIRS1L1C MINGW64 /c/Sameer/iot/exasol
$ openssl x509 -modulus -noout -in cert.crt | openssl.exe md5
(stdin)= d2c6074652768d7a5f5b09b412cf2adb  and they turn out to be proper.

Comment: There are neither `private.pem` not `cert.crt` used in your code. Have you checked it with the `CERT` file you've actually used in your code?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The code i mentioned as part of question has all the three (private key, certificate and ca certificate) in one file, but to check their validity i moved to different files ( private.pem has private key, cert.crt has the certificate)

Comment: Since the order of the data in the file might be relevant please check it with the same files you use in your program.

Comment: It worked, the openssl x509 -modulus -noout -in one.pem | openssl.exe md5 failed i had a bad END CERTIFICATE tag. Thanks a ton!. If you put as an Answer i would close this question.